# What is the effect of UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates with nothing between them?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on a mature iOS app, and for some reason the original developers often appended this to various methods:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

So nothing happens between the two calls, and nothing interesting happens before the calls. I searched and was unable to find a reason for such a pattern.

Is it safe to just remove them? If not, then what might the reason be for them?

Comment: Ownvoted. Wow - I guess I’m the only iOS dev that didn’t know this . I could delete the question and get my 2 points back, but the. Adrian would lose 20. Guess I’ll just man up and live with the minus 2 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates):

> You can also use this method followed by the `endUpdates()` method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.

If it's not related to animating row heights then it has no effect.